# Appium-unhandled exception ENOENT is occuring

Tags: appium

Launching Appium server with command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node.exe lib\server\main.js --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4723 --platform-name Android --platform-version 23 --automation-name Appium --log-no-color

> info: Welcome to Appium v1.4.16 (REV ae6877eff263066b26328d457bd285c0cc62430d)
>   info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4723
>   info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"address":"127.0.0.1","logNoColors":true,"platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"23","automationName":"Appium"}
>   info: Console LogLevel: debug
>   info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"capabilities":[{"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"C:/Users/yjaya/Desktop/app-release-unsigned.apk","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"Nexus","platformVersion":"6.0"}},{"requiredCapabilities":{}}],"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"C:/Users/yjaya/Desktop/app-release-unsigned.apk","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"Nexus","platformVersion":"6.0"},"requiredCapabilities":{}}
>   info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.1 (Java/1.8.0_131)
>   info: [debug] No appActivity desired capability or server param. Parsing from apk.
>   info: [debug] No appPackage desired capability or server param. Parsing from apk.
>   info: [debug] Using local app from desired caps: C:\Users\yjaya\Desktop\app-release-unsigned.apk
>   info: [debug] Creating new appium session f7d1277d-e625-4bc1-a4ad-4902bb5ed25b
>   info: Starting android appium
>   info: [debug] Getting Java version
>   info: Java version is: 1.8.0_131
>   info: [debug] Checking whether adb is present
>   info: [debug] Using adb from C:\Users\yjaya\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
>   info: [debug] Parsing package and activity from app manifest
>   info: [debug] Checking whether aapt is present
>   info: [debug] Using aapt from C:\Users\yjaya\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\aapt.exe
>   info: [debug] Extracting package and launch activity from manifest.
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\yjaya\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\aapt.exe dump badging C:\Users\yjaya\Desktop\app-release-unsigned.apk
>   info: [debug] badging package: com.indsci.iassign
>   info: [debug] badging act: com.indsci.iassign.HomeActivity
>   info: [debug] Parsed package and activity are: com.indsci.iassign/com.indsci.iassign.HomeActivity
>   info: [debug] Using fast reset? true
>   info: [debug] Preparing device for session
>   info: [debug] Checking whether app is actually present
>   info: Retrieving device
>   info: [debug] Trying to find a connected android device
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\yjaya\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
>   info: [debug] 1 device(s) connected
>   info: Found device emulator-5554
>   info: [debug] Setting device id to emulator-5554
>   info: [debug] Waiting for device to be ready and to respond to shell commands (timeout = 5)
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\yjaya\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 wait-for-device
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\yjaya\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "echo 'ready'"
>   info: [debug] Starting logcat capture
>   info: [debug] Getting device API level
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\yjaya\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
>   info: [debug] Device is at API Level 23
>   info: Device API level is: 23
>   info: [debug] Extracting strings for language: default
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\yjaya\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "getprop persist.sys.language"
>   info: [debug] Current device persist.sys.language: 
>   info: [debug] java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\appium_apk_tools.jar" "stringsFromApk" "C:\Users\yjaya\Desktop\app-release-unsigned.apk" "C:\Users\yjaya\AppData\Local\Temp;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\com.indsci.iassign" 
>   info: [debug] No strings.xml for language '', getting default strings.xml
>   info: [debug] java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\appium_apk_tools.jar" "stringsFromApk" "C:\Users\yjaya\Desktop\app-release-unsigned.apk" "C:\Users\yjaya\AppData\Local\Temp;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\com.indsci.iassign"
>   warn: Error getting strings.xml from apk
>   info: [debug] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Output is not an existing readable directory.
>     at io.appium.apktools.StringsXML.e(StringsXML.java:112)
>     at io.appium.apktools.Main.main(Main.java:23)
>
> warn: Could not get strings, continuing anyway
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\yjaya\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "echo '{}' > /data/local/tmp/strings.json"
>   info: [debug] Checking whether aapt is present
>   info: [debug] Using aapt from C:\Users\yjaya\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\aapt.exe
>   info: [debug] Retrieving process from manifest.
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\yjaya\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\aapt.exe dump xmltree C:\Users\yjaya\Desktop\app-release-unsigned.apk AndroidManifest.xml
>   info: [debug] Set app process to: com.indsci.iassign
>   info: [debug] Not uninstalling app since server not started with --full-reset
>   info: [debug] Checking app cert for C:\Users\yjaya\Desktop\app-release-unsigned.apk.
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\verify.jar" C:\Users\yjaya\Desktop\app-release-unsigned.apk
>   info: [debug] App already signed.
>   info: [debug] Zip-aligning C:\Users\yjaya\Desktop\app-release-unsigned.apk
>   info: [debug] Checking whether zipalign is present
>   info: [debug] Using zipalign from C:\Users\yjaya\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\zipalign.exe
>   **> error: Unhandled error: Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\Users\yjaya\AppData\Local\Temp;C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\117522-13276-xudx2z'**
>       at Error (native)
>       at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:747:18)
>       at tempDir (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\node_modules\appium-support\lib\tempdir.js:21:8)
>       at Object.generateName [as path] (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\node_modules\appium-support\lib\tempdir.js:29:20)
>       at [object Object]. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\adb.js:460:30)
>       at [object Object].ADB.checkSdkBinaryPresent (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\adb.js:116:5)
>       at [object Object].ADB.checkZipAlignPresent (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\adb.js:146:8)
>       at [object Object].ADB.zipAlignApk (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\adb.js:457:8)
>       at [object Object]. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\adb.js:496:10)
>       at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:742:7)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
>       at maybeClose (child_process.js:1016:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1088:5) context: [POST /wd/hub/session {"capabilities":[{"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"C:/Users/yjaya/Desktop/app-release-unsigned.apk","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"Nexus","platformVersion":"6.0"}},{"requiredCapabilities":{}}],"d]

Also have done adding Environment variables with sdk path..Still getting the above error.
Can anyone please help me on this.